# Prove that the canonical p-adic expansion of $a\in\mathbb{Q}_p$ terminates

Tags: number-theory, p-adic-number-theory

I am having trouble getting started with the following problem:

Prove that the canonical p-adic expansion of $a\in\mathbb{Q}_p$ terminates (so $a_i = 0$ for all $i \geq N$) if and only if a is a positive rational number whose denominator is a power of p.

Thank you in advance

Comment: Can you prove either direction?

Comment: Have you looked at examples? Like some numbers that don’t seem to satisfy that condition? Like $-1$? Or $1/(1-p)$?